# C# Nested object and concatenation

Tags: c#, linq, nested

I have a list of data like below

```
    OrderID= Order1 |ShipToName= Name1 |ItemNo= 11111 |Quantity= 10  
    OrderID= Order1 |ShipToName= Name1 |ItemNo= 22222 |Quantity= 6  
    OrderID= Order1 |ShipToName= Name1 |ItemNo= 33333 |Quantity= 20  
    OrderID= Order2 |ShipToName= Name2 |ItemNo= 12121 |Quantity= 2  
    OrderID= Order2 |ShipToName= Name2 |ItemNo= 22222 |Quantity= 5  
    OrderID= Order3 |ShipToName= Name3 |ItemNo= 33333 |Quantity= 3
```

and this is my model

```
    class FlatFileModel  
    {  
        FlatFileImports[] flatFileOrders;  
    }  
    class FlatFileImports  
    {  
            public string OrderID { get; set; }  
            public string ShipToName { get; set; }  
            public List<FlatFileImports> LineItems { get; set; }  
    }  
    class LineItems  
    {   
                public string ItemNo { get; set; }  
                public int Quantity { get; set; }  
    }
```

What I would like it to do is consolidate by order number in my flatFileOrders list and then nest the items within that.Something like this.

```
flatFileOrders(3)  
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎Order1‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎   
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎items(3)‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎   
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎itemNo:11111    
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎itemNo:22222    
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎itemNo:33333    
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎Order2‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎    
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎items(2)‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎   
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎itemNo:12121    
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎itemNo:22222    
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎Order3‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎  
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎items(1)‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎  
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎itemNo:33333
```

Haven't had much luck googling this situation as I am not really sure how to describe this other than consolidated and nesting? and I apologize for my horrible formatting in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this line `public List<FlatFileImports> LineItems { get; set; } ` is correct?

Comment: In short, you're trying to create a nested structure from flat data - the opposite of what the class names suggest. You need to load the data into a flat structure first, especially if they are stored in a database, as SQL's `GROUP BY` eliminates detail rows. With LINQ to Objects on the other hand, you can use `GroupBy` to collect all details eg in an `Order` and use further `Select` clauses to construct objects from the collected details, eg `rows.GroupBy(r=>r.OrderId).Select(grp=>new {OrderID=grp.OrderID,Items=grp.Select(d=>new {d.ItemNo,d.Quantity{).ToArray());`

Comment: @Pnagiotis The class name is part of something I'm working on for data imported from an excel file, not SQL. It's brought in as a list by row. I'll try to look at other stackoverflow examples of nested structures from flat data though. Thank you.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I hope so. I am still new to c# and I may be making a mistake with my model so please let me know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Similar to what @PanagiotisKanavos gave me I used
>            var groupedCustomerList = output.GroupBy(u => u.OrderId)
                .Select(grp => new { GroupID = grp.Key, CustomerList = grp.ToList() })
                .ToList();

Comment: So is this question solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Check below please:

```cs
var groupedCustomerList = flatModel.flatFileOrders
    .GroupBy(u => u.OrderID)
    .Select(pair => new
    {
        GroupID = pair.Key,
        Items = pair.Select(p => p.LineItems.Select(li => li.ItemNo))
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry I'm a little new to stackoverflow but here is what gave me the results I needed.

```
var ordersList = output.GroupBy(x => x.OrderId)
                       .Select(grp => new {OrderId = grp.Key, OrderDetail = grp.ToList()})
                        .ToList();
```